# How to Encode H.264 from mobile Camera and packetize it(H.264) to Wowza server over RTP/RTSP

Tags: android, h.264, rtsp, rtp, wowza

I Want to Capture video feed from mobile camera in H.264(either by using Library OR using any Native Support in Android), packetize the H.264 feed to Wowza server over RTSP/RTP.

## How to encode camera video into H.264

## How to Send this Encoded feed over RTSP/RTP to Wowza server

I am beginner with Android, be patient to answer.